# What is the most effective method for handling large scale dynamic data for recommendation system?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, recommendation-engine, large-data

We re thinking on a recommendation system based on large scale data but also looking for a professional way to keeping a dynamic DB structure for working in faster manner. We consider some of the alternative approaches. One is to keep in a normal SQL database but it would be slower compared to using normal file structure. Second is to use nosql graph model DB but it is also not compatible with the algorithms we use since we continuously pull al the data into a matrix. Final approach we think is to use normal files to keep the data but it is harder to keep track and watch the changes since no query method or the editor. Hence there are different methods and the pros and cons. What ll be the your choice and why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you mention "files" and "file structure" so many times, so maybe I'm missing something, but for efficient data processing, you obviously don't want to store things in files. It is expensive to read/write data to disk and it's hard to find something to query files in a file system that is efficient and flexible.

I suppose I'd start with a product that already does recommendations:

http://mahout.apache.org/

You can pick from various algorithms to run on your data for producing recommendations.

If you want to do it yourself, maybe a hybrid approach would work? You could still use a graph database to represent relationships, but then each node/vertex could be a pointer to a document database or a relational database where a more "full" representation of the data would exist.